# por que no puedo iniciar mi servicio de windows visual studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un problema es mi primera vez creando un servicio de windows al principio no me dejaba ejecutar el servicio porque faltaba incluir el Installutil.exe para que el sistema operativo lo pueda registrar y iniciar y detener como tal, ya que no se puede ejecutar desde el propio visual studio entonces para incluirlo o instalarlo hice esto en el símbolo del sistema
ejecute este comando

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"

después esto:

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> installutil.exe "C:\Users\cahernan\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CopiarYPegarArchivos\CopiarYPegarArchivos\bin\Debug\CopiarYPegarArchivos.exe"

y al parecer todo bien ahi me mostro que se installo con exito por que leyendo y viendo videos se navega hasta donde tenemos el archivo installutil y despues entre comillas seria la ruta del proyecto completa hasta su instalador pero aqui el problema esta en que aun que en la consola me muestra que si se instalo me sigue mostrando el error de que no puedo ejecutar desde la linea de comandos o el depurador de visual studio , como puedo solucionar esto ? y cual es mi error?

Comment: ¿Que error muestra al instalar?

Comment: bueno es que sale el error al intentar ejecutar el visual studio de que no se puede ejecutar desde la linea de comandos o el depurador de visual studio cuando ya no deberia aparecer ese mensaje debido a que ya quedo el instalador no entiendo que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, usa el comando "installutil" como administrador, pero sin definir .exe, además asegura que la ruta del .exe de tu servicio sea correcta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes asegurar que tienes permisos de administrador al usar la línea de comandos, además de asegurar que la ruta de tu .exe para el servicio sea correcta.

**Instalar Windows Service en Windows.**

1. Ingresar a línea de comandos, asegurar tienes los suficientes permisos, de otra forma **debes iniciar línea de comandos como administrador para asegurar poder instalar el servicio**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. En línea de comandos ingresa al directorio de tu FrameWork :

   > cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
3. Dentro de este directorio harás uso de la utilería `installutil.exe`, no necesitas escribir la extensión ".exe", ya que se entiende que es un ejecutable, como parámetro debes usar la ruta del servicio, indicando tu archivo .exe

   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> installutil "C:\Users\cahernan\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CopiarYPegarArchivos\CopiarYPegarArchivos\bin\Debug\CopiarYPegarArchivos.exe"

Al realizar este paso podrás instalar sin problema tu servicio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y podrás visualizarlo en los servicios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es importante también que asegures tu servicio no se encuentra previamente instalado, para esto deberás primero detenerlo y desinstalarlo usando `installutil /u` :

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> installutil /u "C:\Users\cahernan\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CopiarYPegarArchivos\CopiarYPegarArchivos\bin\Debug\CopiarYPegarArchivos.exe"
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo si me funciono , te lo agradezco mucho espero que alguien mas si esta en problemas con esto , pueda ver esta pregunta

Comment: @ObedBustos Excelente, saludos!